# Scala Play Overloaded method value [save] cannot be applied

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, save

Getting Overloaded method value [save] cannot be applied to (models.UserReset)

model :

```
case class UserReset (
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  userId: ObjectId,
  email : String,
  key : String,
  used : Boolean = false,
  createDate: Date = new Date()
)
```

Controller :

```
//save reset info
val userResetVal = UserReset(userId = user.id, email = user.email, key = resetLink)
User.save(userResetVal)
```

Not sure why? Or should I include Id, Used and createDate in val userResetVal = UserReset(userId = user.id, email = user.email, key = resetLink)?

Comment: What it means is that there is no method User.save() that would accept an instance of UserReset as it's sole parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `UserReset` to be a separate model from `User`? In this case you also need

```
object UserReset {
  // define the corresponding table structure 
  // and methods including save
}
```

and call

```
UserReset.save(userResetVal)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey.. I just figure out that I miss this code

Comment: this is the answer I missed this part